# Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio 3.0.1, and I got an error:

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Could not create service of type
>   AnnotationProcessorDetector using
>   JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().

Can you help me to understand the above error and let me know how to fix it in android studio 3.0.1?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Got the same problem. Just updated android studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0.1 and got this error. Seems like there is an issue with access. I didn't find out how to manage this in a right manner. But here is what can help, till you find how to solve this in normal way.

Try to run in terminal `sudo /studio.sh`

studio.sh is located in your android-studio/bin folder.

Comment: Above comment was posted as an answer by Alex Podolian. It is more suitable as a comment, but poster did not have enough rep.

Comment: Just a report, if the machine is running out of storage Android Studio may throw this error. Gradle 4.4+Android Studio 3.2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478730/react-native-and-react-native-navigation-error/54684436#54684436

Answer (score 1):

It might be a similar issue to mine. Sometimes gradle deamon has not been stopped after your last gradle command execution failed and you got:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':xxx:compileJava'.
> Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().
```

To fix that you should run:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

and it should display how many deamon workers were active and be able to run gradle task again:

```
  Stopping Daemon(s)
  1 Daemon stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems this issue depend on some errors in your network or firewall  please make sure you have full access internet

Answer (score -2):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
gradle --stop
```

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3708

Comment: It would be better if you could explain why that might fix the problem. It's not clear from the issue link that this did fix the user's problem there - they never replied.