# React-native and react-native-navigation error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have question about react-native-navigation , when i am trying to start my app with command `npm run android` i am getting an error here is the github repo with code 'https://github.com/albert002/learn-react-native' `* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-navigation: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Have you already googled the error. Did you have success running other apps before running into trouble with this one? Did you find out anything useful with the things you mention after "_• Try:_"?

Comment: i already googled , but i can not find the answer , nothing helps :((

Answer (score 1):

first, you should install all dependency by running the following command

> npm install

then

> npm start

to run react native android project 
run

> react-native run-android

this work for me.